# highcharts custombutton hover and press changing colors by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create custom buttons in highcharts using 
"chart.renderer.button" with a default color. however on hover or press the color seems to change by default... i donot want the color to change on hover and button press. Please let me know if there is a simple fix which can be done

here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NxK39/81/

```
    *var testbutton = chart.renderer.button('button1',0, 10)
        .attr({
            id: 'button1',
            fill:'#000000',
            height:20,
            width:40
        })
        .on('click', function () {
        alert("test1");

        })
        .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        })
        .add();*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating button, constructor takes more arguments, from source code:

```
    /**
     * Create a button with preset states
     * @param {String} text
     * @param {Number} x
     * @param {Number} y
     * @param {Function} callback
     * @param {Object} normalState
     * @param {Object} hoverState
     * @param {Object} pressedState
     */
    button: function (text, x, y, callback, normalState, hoverState, pressedState, disabledState, shape) {
        ...
    ),
```

So you shouldn't use `attr()` or `css()` for styles, but use predefined options. For example:

```
var normalState = {
      fill: '#000000',
      style: {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    },
    hoverState = {
      fill: '#000000',
      style: {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    }, 
    pressedState = {
      fill: '#000000',
      style: {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    },
    disabledState = {
      fill: '#000000',
      style: {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    },
    callback = function () {
        console.log('clicked!');
    }

var testbutton = chart.renderer.button('button1', 0, 10, callback, normalState, hoverState, pressedState, disabledState).attr({ ... }).css({ ... }).add()
```

Of course, all options can be the same:

```
var styles = {
      fill: '#000000',
      style: {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    },
    callback = function () {
        console.log('clicked!');
    }

var testbutton = chart.renderer.button('button1', 0, 10, callback, styles, styles, styles, styles).att({ ... }).css({ ... }).add();
```

Live demo of the last one: http://jsfiddle.net/NxK39/82/